# Using jetty server does not return JSON object, error "Current request is not a multipart request"

Tags: json, eclipse, maven

I've got a scenario that does not return a JSON object, when performing a GET request, when invoking the jetty server from the command line (mvn jetty:run).  What is interesting, is that when I use the "Run-Jetty-Run" feature installed within Eclipse, the JSON object is returned.

I am using a Spring rest controller on the back-end with the following annotations:

@RequestMapping(value="/Customer",method=RequestMethod.GET,headers="Accept=application/json")
public List getCustomer(HttpServletRequest request,        @RequestParam(value="customerId", required=true) Integer customerId)

The complete error message is:

org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Current request is not a multipart request
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.handleMissingValue(RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.java:188)

When using "Run-Jetty:Run" debug configuration within eclipse,  the expected results are returned:

[{"customer_id":1,"store_id":1,"district":"Nagasaki","country":"Japan","first_name":"MARY","last_name":"SMITH","email":"MARY.SMITH@sakilacustomer.org","address_id":5,"address":"1913 Hanoi Way","city_id":463,"city":"Sasebo","active":1},...

I am stumped.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded to the latest version of the jetty plugin in my pom file,and the problem was solved:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>9.3.10.v20160621</version>
```